# What are the differences between a Nintendo 3DS and a Nintendo 3DS XL besides screen size?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

I'm looking into buying a 3DS.

Besides Screen size and overall size, are there anymore differences between the regular and the XL version?

Also, can they both play old DS titles?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A quick wikipedia search resulted in this:

Note: I have summarized and paraphrased. [Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nintendo_3DS#Nintendo_3DS_XL).

> - 90% larger screens; the top screen is 4.88 in (124 mm) and the bottom one 4.18 in (106 mm).
> - 86% longer battery life; 1750 mAh lithium-ion battery, lasting 3.5 to 6.5 hours compared to the previous 3 to 5 hours on 3DS games and 6 to 10 hours compared to the previous 5 to 8 hours on original DS games
> - 46% heavier; 336 grams
> - 4 GB SD card comes packaged with the 3DS XL instead of the 2 GB card included with the standard 3DS

To answer your question about original DS games, notice the last part of the second bullet point.

> **5 to 8 hours on original DS games**

Hope that helps.

Comment: It's also worth noting, that DS games running at native resolution look better on the XL than on the original 3DS because they aren't constricted by the small screen size.

Comment: Also worth noting, the XL is significantly more comfortable for teen/adult hands. I know several people who experienced significant hand cramps playing on a regular 3DS that was fixed by upgrading to the 3DS XL